# Error on phonegap gcm plugin and pushwoosh

Tags: cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I follow the tutorial on http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android-gcm-push-notifications-guide/ but I suffered from step 2.

I got this compile error : The method getActivity() is undefined for the type CordovaInterface

ctx.getAcitvity() in PushNotifications.java

I'm sorry that new user aren't allowed to post image.

Is there any things i miss?
This problem appear on both Cordova 1.5 and 1.7.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix it you can do one of the next things:

1. Change Cordova version to 1.9
2. Replace getActivity method with getContext.

But be careful, don't use getContext method with Cordova 1.9 - you will have runtime exception.

I hope it will help.